# Homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Is the following statement true?

---

1. Any finite-dimensional subspace of $C^\infty=\{f\in \mathcal F(\Bbb
       R,\Bbb C) \;|\; f \text{ has derivative of all orders.}\}$ is the
   solution space of a homogeneous linear differential equation with
   constant coefficients.
2. There exists a homogeneous linear differential equation with
   constant coefficients whose solution space has basis $\{t , t^{2}
   \}$.

For the first statement, if I define a set $W=\{ f\in C^\infty \;|\; f=\alpha y=\alpha t \text{ , where $\alpha\in\Bbb C$ and $t\in\Bbb R$} \}$ be the subspace of $C^\infty$ generated by the function $y=t$, where $t\in \Bbb R$. How can I prove that the solution space is $C^\infty $instead of $W$.
If $W$is a solution space of $y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+ \dots +a_1y'+a_0y=0$. Then $a_1+a_0t\neq0$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$. So, $W$ is not a solution space of $y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{n-1}+ \dots +a_1y'+a_0y=0$.

For second statement, if there is a homogeneous linear differential equation with
    constant coefficients whose solution space has basis $\{t , t^{2}
\}$. Since the dimension is 2 for $\{t , t^{2} \}$, the differential equation $a_2y''+a_1y'+a_0y=0$ is of dimension 2. Let $y=t$ then $a_1+a_0t\neq0$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$. So, $t$ is not a solution to $a_2y''+a_1y'+a_0y=0$.

Do my attempt is right?

Comment: It is not clear what the notation 
$$
W=\{ f\in C^\infty \;|\; f=\alpha y=\alpha t \text{ , where }\alpha,t \in\Bbb C\}
$$
is supposed to mean, nor how your work so far addresses the first statement

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I want show that $W$ is the subspace of $C^\infty$ that is generated by the function $y=t$, $t\in \Bbb R$.